# Apache Geode GFSH list all subscriptions to a cache

Tags: gemfire, geode

Like the `list durable-cqs` command is it possible to list all subscriptions by key to a Geode region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not on GFSH but there is GetInterestList() in the region subscription service API.

https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#getInterestList--

Answer (score 2):

You can find the list of all available commands in the [gfsh Command Help](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/gemfire/tools_modules/gfsh/gfsh_command_index.html) site.

That said, I don't think there's a `gfsh` command for this, neither could I find anything related in link I've previously shared.

Cheers.